# What can be read from this error?

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, out-of-memory

I got heap out of memory error in Javascript. But I don't know how to identify the problem that is causing the error.

Error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4321:0x3c60820]   139851 ms: Mark-sweep 1407.8 (1491.9) -> 1407.6 (1463.9) MB, 914.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 915 ms) last resort GC in old space requested
[4321:0x3c60820]   140774 ms: Mark-sweep 1407.6 (1463.9) -> 1407.6 (1463.9) MB, 923.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x27dc0aba5ec1 <JSObject>
    2: new constructor(aka PromiseCapability) [/home/minnak/Darbas/market/app/myccio/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_new-promise-capability.js:7] [bytecode=0x41b44d5679 offset=18](this=0x394dac4abeb9 <PromiseCapability map = 0x13bac1f3eb61>,C=0x27dc0ab95a21 <JSFunction Promise (sfi = 0x27410952fa11)>)
    5: f [/home/minnak/Darbas/market/app/myccio/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_new...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x12190dc [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewStruct(v8::internal::InstanceType) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewTuple3(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::StoreIC::StoreTransition(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::StoreIC::GetMapIndependentHandler(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::IC::ComputeHandler(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::StoreIC::UpdateCaches(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::StoreIC::Store(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::Runtime_StoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/minnak/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node]
13: 0xe9968f0463d
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What useful info should be spotted from this message?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: I guess this `/home/minnak/Darbas/market/app/myccio/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_new-promise-capability.js:7` is the file, and the line the error is in.

Comment: @Pointy I don't even know which part of my backend code causes this, thats the problem.

Comment: Something in your code is using a lot of memory. Maybe use the inspector to trace the code when it's running. The V8 stack trace does not look useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

You just tried to invoke a constructor which couldn't be done because the memory is already full.